# 'HtmlSelect' cannot have children of type 'DataList'

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, database

I'm doing this:

```
<select id="selectBookCategory" name="country" runat="server">

    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="categoryId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

    <ItemTemplate>

        <option value='<%# Eval("categoryId") %>'><%# Eval("categoryName")%></option>

    </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:DataList>

</select>
```

Is there any way that I can do that using any other tag?

Comment: what `other tag` are you looking for?

Comment: you could be a little more specific in what you are trying to do

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do and how you are doing it? When do you get this error?

Comment: Use a datasource for your select list to dynamically generate options from a database. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlselect.datasource?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: It looks like you are using the wrong control, look into the `DropDownList` control

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<select id="selectBookCategory" name="country" runat="server">
  <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="categoryId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <option value='<%# Eval("categoryId") %>'><%# Eval("categoryName")%></option>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:DataList>
</select>
```

is not at all how asp works.  a `DataList` is a server control that,depending on the `RepeatLayout` property renders a `table`, an `ul`, an `ol`, or just a series of `span`s

Based on the snippet in your post it appears you are trying to render a `DropDownList` in which case the code would look like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1 "runat="server"  
                  DataSource="SqlDataSource1" 
                  DataTextField="categoryID" 
                  DataValueField="categoryName" > 
</asp:DropDownList>
```

...and that's all. This will render a `select` html tag using the rows of data from your datasource as `option` tags